# How to post binary using Axios?

Tags: javascript, post, axios

I'm trying to make a post request to a server that accepts a binary file upload with Authentication token in header

I was able to achieve this using XMLHttpRequest(), but are there ways to use axios to achieve the same thing?

I've tried

```
axios.post(url, File, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': File.type,
        'Authentication' : faketoken
    }
})
```

where File is an instance of Html5 File interface, this doesn't work, for some reason when I exam the request header in chrome, the content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

thanks in advance

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can upload a file to an API that accepts binary file upload like this:

```
const file = fs.readFileSync("/path/to/file");
await axios({
    method: 'post',
    url: uploadUrl, //API url
    data: file, // Buffer
    maxContentLength: Infinity,
    maxBodyLength: Infinity
});
```